# Process.Start () with passed through Stdout

Tags: c#, process, stdout

I would like to start a process and read the standard output but also have this read output show up in the console window of the spawned process. Currently using `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;` combined with `BeginOutputReadLine()` causes the output not to show up in the console window. Which is undesirable. Does anyone know how to do this or if it's even possible?

To clarify for the comments.

I have a function that responds to the output from the process, that I set with:

```
    ProcessHandle.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ProcessHandle_OutputDataReceived);

    void ProcessHandle_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
         ... //React to output here.
    }
```

But in doing so the output doesn't make it to the console window of the spawned process, is there any way to manually feed it back to that console so it shows up as if my application had not intercepted it?

Comment: So you want it to be in both the standard window AND your app's Standard Out?

Comment: You can't have it both ways, just not an option.

Comment: There is a command called `tee` in Linux, and you might be able to find something similar on Windows, but I'm not 100% sure if something like this would work in Windows. It could allow you to copy stdout to stderr, and you capture stdout for display in your application and allow stderr to still output to the other process's console window.

Comment: Yes, Console.Write or Console.WriteLine should do what you want.

Comment: Err... If I use Console.Write it will show in my app's console, not in the spawned apps console. tee is very similar to what I want, I'll look around from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var pi = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = prog,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = false
        };

        var proc = new Process { StartInfo = pi };
        try
        {
            if (!proc.Start())
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Starting proc failed!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            proc.WaitForExit();
            if (proc.ExitCode != 0)
            {
                //throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("proc returned exit code {0}", proc.ExitCode));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Unknown problem in proc", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!proc.HasExited)
                proc.Kill();
        }
```

Comment: As you can see, I read the entire output of the proc with ReadToEnd, then Write it to the console.  This works for my purpose, but I've also done a loop reading a line from StandardOutput, and writing a line to the console, which also works, but took more CPU, and as this spawns a very CPU intensive task, I chose to minimize it this way.  The output really is just used for determining if anything went wrong and if so what, so I didn't need a real time update.  I'm also guaranteed a fairly static size from the output as well, so I don't have to worry about the memory constaints.